# UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource snapshot for static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource

In my UICollectionView, I have a header supplementary view that is static and doesn't receive any value to be configured.

So, when I'm creating a snapshot for UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource, I need to pass something like () for this section as a data, to fill the section with something.
But () is not Hashable, so it doesn't work.

So, how to work with the static content like that when I'm generally using diffable data source to populate UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a dummy data structure that conforms to the Hashable protocol and just pass it in?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Comment: In the general case, your answer is correct.
But in my specific case, I need just a header for the whole UICollectionView. So I used the field supplementaryViews in the layout configuration. Also notice that when using this approach, you header will receive the indexpath (0, 0), the same as the first 'real' item of your collection. You have to distinguish those two my elementKind property, which can be a unique key.